# Cursor jumps to the end in Angular6 Json Schema Form input field

Tags: angular6-json-schema-form

If you are using 2-way binding for the data: `Edit an input from the beginning or middle of the string. You will notice after the first character, the cursor will move to the end of the line.`

Can someone help with a workaround with this or is there any way to resolve this?
This [issue](https://github.com/dschnelldavis/angular2-json-schema-form/issues/184) should give you more information about the issue I am talking about here.